# How to coarsen dataset with a custom function?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I want to aggregate my `xarray` `Dataset` to a 1 degree resolution using a custom function:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# aggregate to 1degree, using a custom function
def aggregate_to_1d(ds: xr.Dataset, agg_func):

    # Define the desired output shape (180 lat points and 360 lon points)
    num_lat_points = 180
    num_lon_points = 360

    # Calculate the coarsen factor based on the desired shape
    coarsen_factor_lat = ds.dims['lat'] // num_lat_points
    coarsen_factor_lon = ds.dims['lon'] // num_lon_points

    # coarsen the dataset
    ds_coarsened = ds.coarsen(lon = coarsen_factor_lon, lat = coarsen_factor_lat).reduce(agg_func)

    # return the aggregated dataset
    return ds_coarsened
```

For example, I want to use geometric mean, instead of arithmetic mean:

```
def geometric_mean(arr):
    return np.exp(np.mean(np.log(arr)))
```

Then, when I do:

```
aggregate_to_1d(ds, geometric_mean)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: geometric_mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

**Reproducible data (ds)**:

```
# Create longitude and latitude coordinate values
lon_values = np.linspace(-180, 180, 2880)
lat_values = np.linspace(-90, 90, 1440)

# Create random data with the same dimensions as lon and lat
data = np.random.rand(len(lat_values), len(lon_values))

# Create an xarray DataArray with the data and coordinates
data_array = xr.DataArray(data, dims=('lat', 'lon'), coords={'lon': lon_values, 'lat': lat_values})

# Create an xarray Dataset with the DataArray
ds = xr.Dataset({'random_data': data_array})
```

Comment: I think you want to use this
https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.rolling.DatasetCoarsen.reduce.html#xarray.core.rolling.DatasetCoarsen.reduce